# Change values in dropdown when some characters are entered in textbox using ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am reading csv file in php Having 2 columns in it. what i want is when i enter any character from first column from csv in text box  then i want related values of second column from same csv file to be come in drop down list. i am quite new to use ajax not get any such type of example.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you're looking for: http://www.99points.info/2010/12/n-level-dynamic-loading-of-dropdowns-using-ajax-and-php/

Comment: Thanks for reply, But that is not what i want.. i need a text box to enter values present in csv and dropdown will come with the related values of csv again.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to do, but if you are using jquery, then ajax is very simple. You can use:

```
var sChar = 'c';
$.get('yourPhpFile.php', { sCharacter:sChar }, function(sData){
   alert(sData);
});
```

This way you call yourPhpFile.php, sCharacter is available in yourPhpFile.php as $_GET parameter, and sData holds the output.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/